# How do you save a keras class model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

am having a problem with loading a Keras class model
how to save RecommenderNet model and use it in future
[here](https://keras.io/examples/structured_data/collaborative_filtering_movielens/) are source codes for a recommender system

here is the problem
I used save function to this model and it worked

```
class RecommenderNet(keras.Model):
def __init__(self, num_users, num_movies, embedding_size, **kwargs):
    super(RecommenderNet, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.num_users = num_users
    self.num_movies = num_movies
    self.embedding_size = embedding_size
    self.user_embedding = layers.Embedding(
        num_users,
        embedding_size,
        embeddings_initializer="he_normal",
        embeddings_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(1e-6),
    )
    self.user_bias = layers.Embedding(num_users, 1)
    self.movie_embedding = layers.Embedding(
        num_movies,
        embedding_size,
        embeddings_initializer="he_normal",
        embeddings_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(1e-6),
    )
    self.movie_bias = layers.Embedding(num_movies, 1)

def call(self, inputs):
    user_vector = self.user_embedding(inputs[:, 0])
    user_bias = self.user_bias(inputs[:, 0])
    movie_vector = self.movie_embedding(inputs[:, 1])
    movie_bias = self.movie_bias(inputs[:, 1])
    dot_user_movie = tf.tensordot(user_vector, movie_vector, 2)
    # Add all the components (including bias)
    x = dot_user_movie + user_bias + movie_bias
    # The sigmoid activation forces the rating to between 0 and 1
    return tf.nn.sigmoid(x)


 model = RecommenderNet(num_users, num_movies, EMBEDDING_SIZE)
 model.compile(
loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), 
optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
)
```

but when I used function load_model to predict my data it raises an error

```
model.save("my_model")
loaded_model = keras.models.load_model("my_model")
```

prediction

```
movies_file = data_path + '/product.csv'

movie_df = pd.read_csv(movies_file)

# Let us get a user and see the top recommendations.
user_id = df.userId.sample(1).iloc[0]
movies_watched_by_user = df[df.userId == user_id]
movies_not_watched = movie_df[~movie_df["movieId"].isin(movies_watched_by_user.movieId.values)]["movieId"]
movies_not_watched = list(
    set(movies_not_watched).intersection(set(movie2movie_encoded.keys()))
)
movies_not_watched = [[movie2movie_encoded.get(x)] for x in movies_not_watched]
user_encoder = user2user_encoded.get(user_id)
user_movie_array = np.hstack(
    ([[user_encoder]] * len(movies_not_watched), movies_not_watched)
)


ratings = loaded_model.predict(user_movie_array)



ratings = ratings.flatten()
print(ratings)
```

error I get

```
Could not find matching concrete function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
  Positional arguments (1 total):
    * Tensor("inputs:0", shape=(32, 2), dtype=int32)
  Keyword arguments: {}

 Expected these arguments to match one of the following 2 option(s):

Option 1:
  Positional arguments (1 total):
    * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 2), dtype=tf.int64, name='inputs')
  Keyword arguments: {}

Option 2:
  Positional arguments (1 total):
    * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 2), dtype=tf.int64, name='input_1')
  Keyword arguments: {}

Call arguments received:
  • args=('tf.Tensor(shape=(32, 2), dtype=int32)',)
  • kwargs=<class 'inspect._empty'>
```

Comment: this is just a link to the keras page. but what is the actual problem ?  
Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: have you seen this https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize ?

Comment: You need to be specific in what problem you are having, with all details in the question.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I have already elaborated my problem can you help me?

Comment: I have seen it but It has not Helped me @MinhQuangNguyen

Comment: See here : https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#how_savedmodel_handles_custom_objects - to save whole model (config + weight), you may need to implement get and from config. Or, you can save the weight and reload it.